# How to let Gradle ignore failure of a `dependsOn` task?

Tags: gradle

I have a custom Gradle task that defines a dependency:

```kotlin
tasks.register('someTask') {
    dependsOn "dependentTask"
    dependsOn "otherTask"
    dependsOn "moreTask"
}
```

Now, if `otherTask` fails, I'd like to still continue all the other tasks *and have the whole Gradle run succeed*. Simply put, the result of `otherTask` should be completely ignored.

I'd be okay configuring this on `otherTask`, or on the `dependsOn` statement, but it needs to be a single `gradlew` command line invocation. No calling `otherTask` separately with `./gradlew otherTask --continue`.

Is this even possible with Gradle?